# I've added a Jar to my IDE classpath on Codename One and now my cloud builds fail

Tags: java, codenameone

I added a JAR for JSON parsing to my NetBeans classpath when building my application. Everything worked great in the simulator but I got a build error from the build servers as I try to build the native app.

How can I parse JSON or use arbitrary JAR's in Codename One?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One has builtin support for JSON in the `JSONParser` class.

However, the bigger question at hand is changing the classpath which Codename One doesn't allow since the native JAR might not work on the mobile device. This is explained in [this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/jaring-and-libraries.html) which is a bit old but the basic reasoning is:

- An arbitrary JAR might use an API that isn't supported by Codename One.
- An arbitrary JAR might be compiled with a compiler that generates bytecodes that are untested with the build servers (e.g. in the past Eclipse ADT had some issues with the old VM).
- Codename One's build process doesn't know the JAR is there and doesn't send it to the servers.
- The most common case is using native libraries and JAR's don't have builtin support for native code on mobile devices.

To solve these issues Codename One has a cn1lib file format and a [list of available cn1lib libraries](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html). You use them by placing a cn1lib in the lib directory and pressing "Refresh Libs" in the context menu.

cn1libs support native code, hints on code completion and will work for native builds "as is". Steve did a thorough tutorial on porting the native iOS/Android Freshdesk SDK to Codename One [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html).

Comment: You can do that? Ask a question with the intent of answering it yourself?

Comment: Yes, there is a checkbox when asking a question. This was asked in private email so my response to the person asking was to link to the answer so it will be a part of public record.